Joining tables when values are missing
I have the following query to get the names of categories and subcategories for items given by an ID:
SELECT a.value, b.value FROM X a
INNER JOIN X b ON a.ID = a.ID
               AND a.NAME = 'Category'
               AND b.NAME = 'Subcategory'

The issue is that sometimes my categories do not have any subcategories. In that case, there is no row for Subcategory for that ID. Removing b.NAME = 'Subcategory' is not really an option either since there are over fifty distinct values for X.NAME. Do I have any other option than creating an X.NAME = 'Subcategory' with X.value = NULL in cases subcategory is missing?
So, I want a query which returns the Category and a NULL value when subcategory is missing.
Here's some sample data:
insert into X values ('10101', 'Category', 'Murder');
insert into X values ('10101', 'Subcategory', 'Strangulation');
insert into X values ('15151', 'Category', 'Theft');
insert into X values ('15151', 'Subcategory', 'Vehical');
insert into X values ('15151', 'Severity', 'High');
insert into X values ('33456', 'Category', 'Theft');
insert into X values ('45565', 'Category', 'Murder');
insert into X values ('45565', 'Severity', 'Low');
insert into X values ('76543', 'Category', 'Violence');
insert into X values ('76543', 'Subcategory', 'Domestic Violence');
insert into X values ('76543', 'Severity', 'Medium');


Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Use left join and put last part of where clause into join condition.

The tooltip from tag sql says: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL."

Expanding on @Arvo's answer, something like: select * from X a left join X b on b.id = a.id and b.Name = 'Subcategory' where a.name = 'Category'

Side note. I created this db<>fiddle with the intent to show that Thorsten Kettner's answer below has the same result and execution plan as the SQL in Arvo's and siggemannen's comments above, but I was not able to get the second table reference to use an index seek when wrapped in a CTE or subquery. I would have expected the various forms to be equivalent and use similar execution plans. Using views enables index seeks, as does changing the left-join to an inner-join. Does anyone know why or is this just a limitation of the optimizer.

You are dealing with an EAV (entity - attribute - value) table. An entity represented by the column ID has different attributes (name), each with its own value. It sometimes helps readability to use CTEs (in a WITH clause) for the attributes. Then you can treat each attribute/name as it it were a separate table. Your query equals
WITH
  cat AS (SELECT id AS entity, value AS category FROM x WHERE name = 'Category'),
  sub AS (SELECT id AS entity, value AS subcategory FROM x WHERE name = 'Subcategory')
SELECT cat.category, sub.subcategory
FROM cat
INNER JOIN sub ON sub.entity = cat.entity;

Now, if you want to get categories without subcategories, too, change the inner join into an outer join, just as you would do with any other table.
WITH
  ...
SELECT cat.category, sub.subcategory
FROM cat
LEFT OUTER JOIN sub ON sub.entity = cat.entity;

